# Problema ao tentar pegar o $scope do form com Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho o seguinte `form` que fica dentro de um modal:

```
<form name="usuarioForm"  novalidate="">
```

No final desse `form` tenho um botão onde passo o objeto que foi preenchido para uma função, e nessa função eu tento limpar o form dessa forma:

```
$scope.usuarioForm.$setPristine();
```

Porém recebo esse erro:

> Error: $scope.usuarioForm is undefined

Outra coisa que notei, quando tento limpar o objeto dessa forma: `$scope.usuario = "";` após salvar os dados nada acontece também. Ou seja, dá a impressão que esse modal não está dentro do controller.

Eu coloquei esse modal dentro da minha página que possui o controller: `loginCtrl` dessa forma:

```
<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
   <ion-modal-view class="back">
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
       <h1 class="title">Novo Usuário</h1>
   </ion-header-bar>
   <ion-content >
   <form name="usuarioForm"  novalidate="">
   ...//Todo código da página

   <button class="button button-block button-positive" 
        type="submit" ng-click="salvar(usuario)"      
        ng-disabled="usuarioForm.$invalid">
        <i class="ion-checkmark"></i>
        Cadastrar
   </button>
   </form>
   </ion-content>
   </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.salvar = function(usuario) {
    usuarioAPI.saveUsuario(usuario).success(function(data) {
      console.log("Salvar!");
      delete $scope.usuario;
      $scope.usuarioForm.$setPristine();
      $scope.closeModal();


    })
    .error(function(response, status) {
      console.log("erro " + status);

    });

  }
```

Código de abertura do modal:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
```

Comment: como está o código do seu controller?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código da função salvar que fica no controller

Comment: Poderia incluir também o código de abertura da modal? Creio que será importante para definir o problema.

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria

Comment: @Techies cara, não consegui ti ajudar, me parece tudo ok, o form deveria ter sido atribuido para o scope.

Comment: Sim, ta estranho no Angular funciona, outra coisa que não está funcionando também é quando eu tento pega rum objeto, por exemplo: `$scope.usuario.nome` da erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tive esse problema, resolvi da seguinte forma: 
 - No seu button você pode passar o form dessa forma: **ng-click="salvar(usuario, usuarioForm)"**. 
 - Troque a chamada da function por  **$scope.salvar = function(usuario, form)** 
 - Na hora do pristine você coloca **form.$setPristine()**; 
Para mim resolveu, sempre reseta o form que esta trabalhando.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema parece ser a modal criando um novo scope.
O correto seria debugar no chrome, setar breakpoints e analisar a variável $scope e tal.

Já que você setou o scope da modal, você pode tentar acessar o scope pai assim:

```
$scope.$parent.usuarioForm.$setPristine();
```