# Como limpar campo de input com angular?

Tags: angularjs

estou tentando limpar o campo de texto, após o submit, mas não estou conseguindo.
Seguem os meu códigos

html:
Aqui no html, mudei de ng-model="msg" para mensagem.msg 
    
        
            
              
            
            Enviar

angular:

```
$scope.mensagem = {
    msg:""
  };
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {
    var enviaMsg = {
        msg: mensagem,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome')
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){

        pegaMsgsLogra();
        $scope.mensagem = {
             msg:""
            };
    });
}
```

Recebo essa mensagem no console:

> TypeError: $scope.msgForm.$setPristine is not a function

Comment: Se você tirar isso: `delete msgForm` e isso `$scope.msgForm = []` não funciona?

Comment: Não, continua o mesmo aviso e não acontece nada.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AhGDC/243/

Comment: Apareceu isso no console
TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Comment: Consegui.
Vou postar aqui a solução

Comment: Veja se esse post te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94951/problema-ao-tentar-pegar-o-scope-do-form-com-ionic/113532#113532

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
$scope.form = {}; //Definido logo no inicio do controller

$scope.form.msgForm.$setPristine(); //Definido no local onde deve ser feito a limpeza
```

E em seu html:

```
<form name="form.msgForm">
```

Normalmente isso acontece pois muitas vezes sua `view` é alternada ou o formulário é inicializado após o `controller`. Deste modo ele mantém referência ao formulário.

---

Para apagar o campo do `input`, você deve usar a mesma referência do `ng-model` e NÃO do nome do formulário. No seu caso, deve ser assim:

```
delete $scope.msg;
```

Assim você pode remover todas as definições `$scope.msgForm = [];` do seu `controller`.

Comment: Nada, o texto continua no campo.

Comment: E o console, o que mostra?

Comment: Nada também. Pelo menos isso kkkkkk

Comment: @GustavoSevero Editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada

Comment: Nada ainda... Ta bem complicado.

Comment: Conseguiiiiiiii!!!!!!
Vou postar aqui o como ficou... Tive que mudar o nome do ng-model

Comment: Será que você não tinha uma dupla declaração com o nome $scope.msg?

Comment: @GustavoSevero sua solução pode resolvido, mas a limpeza do seu formulário não está completa. Não usar $setPristine() não reseta o estado do seu formulário, ele vai ficar com algum lixo do preenchimento anterior.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete $scope.msg;

$scope.msgForm.$setPristine();
```

Tenta isso

Comment: $scope.mensagem não possui nenhuma definição e `mensagem` é apenas um obj js. Deste modo, nada vai acontecer.

Comment: verdade, vi errado o form dele. No caso eu colocaria no ng-model, ng-model="mensagem.msg". Ae creio que funcione, mas como no caso só tem um input talvez não seja necessario

Comment: Na verdade era a referência dele que estava errada. Ele estava tentando apagar o formulário ao invés do campo. Veja minha resposta. =D